# Как сделать задержку без time

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, время

Вообщем хочу сделать ожидание в 7 секунд на python, но так-как это телеграмм бот, а значить сделать time.sleep нельзя, я обращаюсь к вам.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["win"])

def set_ro(message):
    Time = [1920, 2760, 3480, 4440]
    ro_msg = ["32 минуты", "46 минут", "58 минут", "74 минуты"]`

X = random.randint(1, 4)
bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id, until_date=time()+Time[X])
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы выйграли RO на " + ro_msg[X],
                     reply_to_message_id=message.message_id)
```

Comment: Почему это нельзя?..

Comment: Вы можете воспользоваться многопоточностью, чтобы для каждого действия бота выделять отдельный поток и не стопорить при этом главную программу.